# traffic light sequence lights won't change

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a traffic light simulation using html and JavaScript. I managed to get the starting image to display but the button just doesn't work.

Comment: i thought it didnt matter what it was called because it is a function name

Comment: Sorry, I edited my previous comment before I saw your reply, but I wasn't commenting on the name of the function, I was indirectly pointing out what the answer below is saying.

Comment: Valid values for the id attribute in HTML doesn't contain space inside two word. See This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just take this (you ought to run this with Internet)

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change to the next light.</p>

<img id="starting_light" src="http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png">

<button type="button" onclick="nextLightClick()">Next Light</button>

<script>

var lights = new Array("http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/sk/images/thumb/1/1f/Red_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Red_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Yellow_Light_Icon.svg/232px-Yellow_Light_Icon.svg.png","https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Green_Light_Icon.svg");



var index = 0;
var lightsLen = lights.length;

function nextLightClick() {
    index++;

    if (index == lightsLen) 
        index = 0;

    var image = document.getElementById('starting_light');
    image.src = lights[index];
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like he needs the relative path in the array as well?

Comment: it is still not functioning

Comment: i have tried putting the folder links which i think is the relative path in aswell but it didnt work so i changed it back

Comment: Take out the `index =` part. Just `index++;` on its own is all you need.

Comment: oh yeah, just changed it, doesnt seem to be making a difference

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `starting light` as an id, you can read more here as pointed in the comments [Valid Naming for ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Also change `index=` to `index++`

You also seem to have a typo, as well as a missing curly braces in the `nextLightClick()` function. Let me know if this helps!

P.S make sure all the pictures are named properly and in the same directory!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use '_' or '-' instead of space in id (`starting-light`).
2. If all the images are in the `./ict traffic lights/` folder, then change the image names in the array to be like `"./ict traffic lights/red.jpg", "./ict traffic lights/redamber.jpg"` etc.
3. Remove extra brace after  `index = index ++;` line cause otherwise 
   `if (index == lightsLen)...` part of the code remains outside of the `nextLightClick()` function.

Comment: i have tried the image links in the array and it doesnt make a difference for some reason

Comment: try using &nbsp; in your folder names instead of space

Comment: oh sorry not &nbsp; but %20